# smartmontools Bad Block How To for Windows

Tags: windows, smart, bad-blocks

There's a tutorial on how to deal with bad blocks detected by
Smart checks [(click here to see)](http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/badblockhowto.html).
 Unfortunately, it uses some tools only available on
Linux (fdisk, etc). 
I'd like to know if there is Windows equivalents
for these tools?

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the filesystem specific bits in that guide as they are irrelevant.  The important part is identifying the bad block and writing to it.  This is done with `dd` and you should be able to find a windows port of that in msys or cygwin or something.  If the bad sector happened to be part of a file then the file will be corrupted.